# How to create new service in the swarm without restarting other services using "docker stack"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-stack

**Tried:** I have added new service in docker-compose.yml file and ran "`docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml myservice`". But this command restarts all the services and start the newly added service.

**Description:**
I have set of services deployed in swarm mode and these services are dependant on each other for eg. ngnix, postgres etc.

Now I want to add new service which is not related to existing deployed services.

I do not prefer `docker service` command to deploy new service.

Is it possible to create new service to existing stack using `docker stack deploy` command?